# Nodes - Knife project via Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

Is it possible to knife project via the Geometry Nodes?

Comment: No. Knife project is a mesh tool.

Comment: Could you please add a little bit more information ? Knife project could mean a lot of things. Is it meant to be one object cutting through another, or along an arbitrary axis, or along an arbitrarily defined curve, etc. ?

Comment: Are you trying to add / extrude / emboss text to an object?

Comment: One object cutting through another object

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to cut an object with geometry nodes along a plane (or whatever) , right?

If so, then the solution is relatively simple:

Use the node `Mesh Boolean` and select the option *Difference* there.

[image]